# Will jquery cache the elements when we query with ID(#)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I query element with id in jQuery, will it cache or will it iterate through DOM?

Comment: Which cache are you talking about???

Comment: Guys... ease up on the down votes. This is a reasonable question for a newbie (if not specifically code related). it is important to know how the browser caches lookups :) Close it, but please don't beat them to death first :>

Comment: @GoneCoding Yes but it is quite unclear question imho especially that this has nothing to do with jQuery. Although your answer is great :)

Comment: Just throwing a downvote without helping to focus the question is exactly what's wrong with StackOverflow today :(

Answer (score 3):

Lookup by ID hits a fast browser dictionary (your cache I suspect), which has one entry per ID.

It is superfast and the DOM is not iterated.

Side note: Lookup by class uses a similar approach in modern browsers, but with multiple elements per class name and is almost as fast as an ID lookup nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't cache.

jQuery will work roughly like this:

1. When you fire up `$("#myid")`, it calls a global `jQuery` function that [passes your query to a function `jQuery.fn.init`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1b9575b9d14399e9426b9eacdd92b3717846c3f2/src/core.js#L34)
2. It [matches your input with regexp](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/core/init.js#L42)
3. It finds that your query started with `#` and [passes it to native `getElementById` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/core/init.js#L79)

And that's it. There's no cache in between, since the `getElementById` call is already super-fast.

Comment: That last part misses one important point. `getElementById` does have a cache behind it (which is why it is so fast). All modern browsers cache elements by id and any classes.

Comment: Sure, but that depends of the implementation of the underlying browser. I assumed that the underlying question was about "can I depend on the jQuery always asking the browser or does it implement its own cache", so that's what I answered for :)